# Can VSTS online be configured to build ng 5 (latest cli) project?

Tags: angular, azure-devops, command-line-interface, azure-pipelines

If VSTS capable of building angular 5 projects that are created from latest ng cli?

The VSTS settings say [edited] npm/5.6.0 node/v8.10.0 linux x64 and currently fail on the build step "ng build".

If the npm install step didn't fail, why wouldn't it find ng via the node_modules directoy?

The error is "sh: 1: ng: not found"

```
    {
    "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.2.0",
    "angular-font-awesome": "^3.1.2",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.19"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "~1.7.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~4.1.0",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~2.5.3"
  }
```

Comment: Is the version of node at least 6.9.0? What is the error you get when the build fails?

Comment: Hi @R.Richards, I edited the information. Locally, I have ng installed globally, but on VSTS is it local to the project/directory. ng build is failing because it can't find ng.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41615804/angular-cli-vso-continuous-integration) may be helpful. That answer is installing the old version of the CLI (angular-cli), so it would need to be updated to install the new version (@angular/cli), so watch for that.

Comment: Turns out the issue was I didn't have the correct path set for the package.json -- problem solved.